# How to check if a thread is running?

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm developing an android app in which I want a particular function to be executed on a different thread. Now, when this thread is running, I don't want another thread to be created. So basically, I want the main thread to check if the thread is running and if it is, I want it to bypass the thread; If it is not then I want it to create a thread and execute that function. How do I do this?

Comment: Ok, so you know a bit about threads. What does the `Thread` interface offer? Hint: see `isAlive()`.

Comment: Run a while(true) loop in the thread.  Have the thread wait at the top on some synchro object.  When you want your function executed, signal the synchro.  No dubious checks required.

Comment: that requires CPU cycles. it's best to add a separate class which sends an event if the thread is done. In the meanwhile, the isBusyFlag stays at true if the event didn't have sent yet. That requires less CPU cycles.

Comment: Waiting on a synchro requires no CPU cycles.  There is another solution that requires less?   :)

Answer (score 4):

you can check [Thread.isAlive()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isAlive%28%29) method.

> It tests if this thread is alive. A thread is alive if it has been
>   started and has not yet died.

Comment: If Thread.isAlive returns true, is the thread still alive by the time it returns?

Comment: @Ty221 OK.  I wonder how the Thread.isAlive call prevents the thread from terminating normally just after it has checked it's state but before returning?

Comment: @MartinJames When the function is returning something is automatically breaking. It can't check something after returning.

Comment: @Ty221 - exactly.  Anyone using this call will be acting on stale information.  IMHO, all these 'thread/task state checks' are fatally flawed.

Answer (score 2):

I will rather advice to use a `Future` in such cases. Have your code as a `FutureTask`. Using `Future.isDone` will tell you if the `Future` is completed or not. And if yes, will also return you the value.

The good part is that you can use the same thread to execute multiple blocks of code as Future.

Currently if you do :

```
Runnable myRunnable;
Thread t = new Thread(myRunnable);
```

Now you should:

```
Future<Void> future = new FutureTask<Void>(myRunnable);
ExecutorService ex= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
ex.submit(future);
```

`future.isDone` will give you your desired. You can keep reusing `ex`

Comment: If Future.isDone returns false, is the Future definitely not completed by the time the call returns?

Comment: Yes. The documentation confirms that.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm very dubious of any of these 'IsAlive', 'IsDone' calls that return some indication of the state of a thread/task that is executing concurrently, probably on another core.  Bt the time the boolean is retuned, it may no longer be valid.

Comment: @MartinJames The Java Memory model guarrantees it. And why will boolean not be valid?. Future will only give information about its FutureTask. If a new future is executed by same thread, it will have its own future. ALl this was the whole point of reimplementing the memory model for 1.5

Answer (score 0):

I have used this, and its working fine

```
if (thread.getState() == Thread.State.NEW)
{
     thread.start();
}
```